# Why the elements of the first matrix are lists and the elemens of the second one are ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

I tied to add variables the the second matrixs, that doesnt change the type, I cant find out whats the diffrence between the two.

```
myu1, myu2, myu3 = np.random.uniform(0,0.5,3)
A = np.array([
    [1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,M1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,-1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-M2,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,M3],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-M3,0,0],
    [myu1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,myu2,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,myu3,0,0,-1,0,0,0]
])
print(type(A[0]))
g= np.array([
    [3,4,5,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,7,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,322,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [3,4,5,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,7,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,322,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [3,4,5,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,7,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
    [5,6,322,-1,5,6,7,7,8,9],
])
print(type(g[0]))
```

Comment: What are `M1`, `M2` and `M3`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].